# Sjudoku II - A greater challenge in the world where 9 is 7

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

This is more difficult instance of a [puzzle posted here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104712/sjudoku-in-a-world-where-9-is-replaced-by-7).

Rules similar to Sudoku applies:

- In each disk, the numbers 1,2,...7 should appear exactly once.
- No line may contain duplicate digits (note that there are lines in 3 directions).

Solution is unique, and can be found by using classical sudoku-strategies.

[image: sjudoku 2]

Comment: This one also looks to be symmetric - are there any *asymmetric* solutions, I wonder?

Comment: What does asymmetric solutions mean in this context? I chose positions of hints in a symmetric manner, as this is common for sudokus. But note that the values are not symmetric

Comment: I mean that it appears that rotating it 180 degrees and permuting the digits gives you the same puzzle. The *solution* is going to be symmetric up to permuting the 7 digits: every 3 will be opposite a 1, every 4 will be opposite a 5, every 6 will be opposite a 7.

Comment: (And the same is true of 60-degree rotations, not just 180-degree. The permutation isn't a simple digit swap, but it appears that we could create a consistent permutation that would work -- which leads me to question whether *all* solutions are the same, just with permuted digits.)

Comment: @Deusovi From the puzzle itself, the 180-degree symmetry is clear. From the answer, there is indeed a 60-degree symmetry given by the permutation `(1, 7, 4, 3, 6, 5)`.

Comment: @Deusovi I tried a little bit to construct an asymmetric solution, but failed. My feeling is that, even if not unique, the solution space is quite small. There are just too many restrictions.

Comment: @Deusovi Given the solution of a single disc, there only three ways to fill all of the remaining discs.

Comment: @DanielMathias Ah yes, i realized this now too! I was convinced the solutions space was much larger, but seems not! How did you prove this (I used a computer).

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

> [image]

Steps:

I didn't find it very difficult. It's basically just normal Sudoku techniques.

However I don't really know how to describe my process...

> [image]
>
>  Start with some obvious 2's.

> [image]
>
>  This leads to the completion of all 2's.

> [image]
>
>  Now we can fill in all the 4's and 5's.

> [image]
>
>  The remaining is quite straightforward from this point.